# How to install python3.6 in parallel with python 2.7 in Ubuntu 18

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

Setting up to start python for data analytics and want to install python 3.6 in Ubuntu 18.0 . Shall i run both version in parallel or overwrite 2.7 and how ? I am getting ambiguous methods when searched up.

Answer (score 0):

Try pyenv and/or pipenv . Both are excellent tools to maintain local python installations.